# "TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'newline'" in my parsing code

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests

So this is my parsing code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import codecs

CSV = 'cards.csv'
HOST = 'https://minfin.com.ua'
URL = 'https://minfin.com.ua/cards/'

HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url,params = ''):
    r  = requests.get(url,headers = HEADERS,params = params)
    return r 

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'product-item product-item-holder')
    cards = []

    for item in items:
        cards.append(

            {

            'title': item.find('div',class_ = 'title').get_text(strip = True),
            'link_product' : HOST + item.find('div', class_ = 'title').find('a').get('href'),
            'brand' : item.find('div', class_ = 'brand').get_text(strip = True),
            'card_image': HOST + item.find('div',class_ = 'image').find('img').get('src')

            }

            )

    return cards

def save_doc(items,path):
    with codecs.open(path, 'w','utf-16',newline = '') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter = ';')
        writer.writerow(['Название Продукта','Ссылка на Продукт','Название Банка','Картинка'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'],item['link_product'],item['brand'], item['card_image']])

def parse():
    PAGE = input("Сколько страниц спарсить: ")
    PAGE = int(PAGE.strip())
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        cards = []
        for page in range(1,PAGE):
            print(f'Парсим страницу: {page}')
            html = get_html(URL,params = {'page' : page})
            cards.extend(get_content(html.text))
            save_doc(cards,CSV)
        pass
    else:
        print("Error")

parse()
```

and this is an error that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\win10\Desktop\path\PARSING\parsing.py", line 74, in <module>
    parse()
  File "C:\Users\win10\Desktop\path\PARSING\parsing.py", line 69, in parse
    save_doc(cards,CSV)
  File "C:\Users\win10\Desktop\path\PARSING\parsing.py", line 49, in save_doc
    with codecs.open(path, 'w','utf-16',newline = '') as file:
TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'newline'
```

At first, there was a Unicode error and the CSV file could not display normally Russian letters. So I added utf-16 and "codecs" module in my code, but now I get this error. This is website  that i'm trying to parse https://minfin.com.ua/cards/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*added utf-16 and "codecs" module in my code, but now I get this error.*

`open` itself does accept `encoding` as argument, try replacing:

```
with codecs.open(path, 'w','utf-16',newline = '') as file
```

using

```
with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-16', newline='') as file
```

and check effect of running such altered code.